# Best configuration for a software RAID 10 SSD for VM xenserver

Tags: raid, ssd, xenserver

I have xenserver servers.

For storage of virtual machines, I use the software RAID 10 (the disks are directly in the servers).

I would like to know the best configuration for 4 SSD disk in RAID 10 software (it is general public
  discs, yes I did this stupidity 1 year ago ..)

Because I made a RAID 10 with 512K and I feel that it is bad.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Back in the days, Linux software RAID (MDRAID) used 64K chunks for RAID 0/10 layouts. Small chunk size, while favoring sequential transfers, proved to be suboptimal for mechanical HDDs facing random I/O access pattern so common in server (and hypervisor) workload, leading to the decision to increase the default to 512K chunksize.

In other words, while you are using SSDs rather than HDDs, I do not think your perceived slowness is related to your current RAID 10 chunk size (512K). Rather, consumer SSDs are quite poor at handling synchronized writes (ie: the kind of writes issued by databases and filesystem journals). If you have an fsync-rich workload, you may be facing this specific issue.

Comment: So what do you advise? 64 KB?